# ReactJS - How to get the whole render Tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do i access *all* the elements in the render tree of a react component, and no `.props.children` will not work nor can I use `refs`.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
// the following is the code inside the `render` function
// for a component called AwesomeLayer
// this.draw is the drawing function for ctx.
<LayoutLayer>
  <SomeOtherLayer>
    <Drawable onAnimationFrame={this.draw} />
  </SomeOtherLayer>
</LayoutLayer>
```

Now I have a top level container called `SurfaceLayer`
The surface layer is supposed to visit all its child elements one after the other on propsChange and then find all the drawables and cache that response for future rafs on any update this is purged.

But if the `SurfaceLayer` is composed like the following

```
<SurfaceLayer>
    <AwesomeLayer />
</SurfaceLayer>
```

I won't get reference to the drawable, because the children of the AwesomeLayer node will be undefined. PS This code may be used by others and so I would not rely on explicit refs as they will cause more errors.

How i have done it now is I mantain a singleton `store` for the whole UI layer which keeps a reference to all the ui elements, (which I feel is bad), is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: `<AwesomeLayer />` - awesome!

Comment: Ran out of names and didn't want to make it go 
`DrawableLayoutLayerWithSomeOtherLayerContainer` (the java style)

Comment: Absolutely! The term chosen is far more elegant!

Comment: Why not have each drawable listen to an event?

Comment: What I'm about to suggest is probably best as a mixin (or perhaps using non-React JS functions):  assuming you're authoring all the components, you could always pass a function (say, `_registerChild`) as a prop to all your components and then in the child, invoke that prop'ed function upon `componentDidMount()` in each child.  That way the children also inform the parent, the parent keeps a list and you can recurse if you add a `for_children()` function that just calls whatever function in the children you want to all components.  Again, probably best as a mixin.

Comment: I may be missing something, but why do you need to call a function for all children on `propsChange`? Could you not just update the props of the direct child `AwesomeLayer` and then listen to propsChange inside `AwesomeLayer` and react to that change?

Comment: Having to face a similar issue, I did exactly as you, storing the ui components in a store singleton.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a little bit against the react.js flow, where you propagate updates in a top-down manner, without needing to worry about the actual children. Also it seems you are trying to access refs from an ancestor of the element rather than from its parent, which might not be that easy. What you can do is to add a ref to `AwesomeLayer` and ask that ref about its children, for example by adding a `getAwesomeChildren()` method to the `AwesomeLayer` component.